# Unable to capture remote client data with nohup and socat

Tags: socat, nohup

I need to capture the verbose and debug output of `socat` running on a remote server.

I can achieve the above when running `socat` in the foreground:

```
$ socat -x -d -d -d tcp-l:8080,bind=0.0.0.0,fork,reuseaddr - 2>stderr.log >stdout.log
```

However, **no output is received in `stdout.log` if the above is run `nohup`'ed in the background**:

```
$ nohup socat -x -d -d -d tcp-l:8080,bind=0.0.0.0,fork,reuseaddr - 2>stderr.log >stdout.log &
```

Here is `stderr.log` right after I start the `nohup` `socat` version above:

```
nohup: ignoring input
2024/03/24 20:06:22 socat[28360] I socat by Gerhard Rieger and contributors - see www.dest-unreach.org
2024/03/24 20:06:22 socat[28360] I This product includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit. (http://www.openssl.org/)
2024/03/24 20:06:22 socat[28360] I This product includes software written by Tim Hudson (tjh@cryptsoft.com)
2024/03/24 20:06:22 socat[28360] I setting option "bind" to "0.0.0.0"
2024/03/24 20:06:22 socat[28360] I setting option "fork" to 1
2024/03/24 20:06:22 socat[28360] I setting option "so-reuseaddr" to 1
2024/03/24 20:06:22 socat[28360] I socket(2, 1, 6) -> 5
2024/03/24 20:06:22 socat[28360] W ioctl(5, IOCTL_VM_SOCKETS_GET_LOCAL_CID, ...): Inappropriate ioctl for device
2024/03/24 20:06:22 socat[28360] I starting accept loop
2024/03/24 20:06:22 socat[28360] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:8080
```

I next connect to port `8080` from netcat,

```
$ nc localhost 8080
```

and this is what `stderr.log` then catpures:

```
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] I accept(5, {2, AF=2 127.0.0.1:37910}, 16) -> 6
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] N accepting connection from AF=2 127.0.0.1:37910 on AF=2 127.0.0.1:8080
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] I permitting connection from AF=2 127.0.0.1:37910
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] N forked off child process 28563
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] I close(6)
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] I still listening
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:8080
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28563] I just born: child process 28563
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28563] I close(4)
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28563] I close(3)
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28563] I just born: child process 28563
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28563] I close(5)
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28563] N reading from and writing to stdio
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28563] I resolved and opened all sock addresses
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28563] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [0,1]
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28563] E read(0, 0x60485184f000, 8192): Bad file descriptor
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28563] N exit(1)
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28563] I shutdown(6, 2)
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] N childdied(): handling signal 17
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] I childdied(signum=17)
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] I childdied(17): cannot identify child 28563
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] I waitpid(): child 28563 exited with status 1
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] I waitpid(-1, {}, WNOHANG): No child processes
2024/03/24 20:06:59 socat[28360] I childdied() finished
```

I next type some text in the netcat terminal and press ENTER.

However, the issue is: **Not only netcat exits, I don't see the text I typed in `stdout.log` either**.

Besides shedding light on what is going on here, can someone kindly also suggest how to capture stderr and stdout of a `nohup`'ed `socat`? Essentially, I need to capture the `-v` and `-d -d -d` output in `stderr.log` and any and all data sent by a remote socket client to `stdout.log` .

Comment: Kamil's answer does a great job of explaining the problem and how to fix it. As an alternative, you might want to try running such commands in a terminal emulator such as `tmux` or `screen`, which allow you to keep a detached session running. For some situations, that is a better solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Explanation

It's about stdin of `socat`.

For a command run in the background with `&`, there are basically two possibilities:

- If job control is disabled in the shell (this is the default for scripts), stdin of the command shall be redirected (before any explicit redirections are performed) to `/dev/null` or an equivalent file.
- If job control is enabled in the shell (this is the default in interactive usage), stdin of the command is what you expect, so it may be the terminal. If it's the terminal, the command in the background cannot steal input from it; if it tries then it will get SIGTTIN. Still you can bring the command to the foreground with `fg` and *then* it can read from the terminal.

`nohup` on its own redirects standard streams away from the terminal, so even in the latter case your `socat` in the background or any of its children/threads/whatever will get the EOF condition (or some error) immediately when it tries to read from its stdin.

You should be able to pass data quickly with like `echo message | nc localhost 8080`, `socat` handling this particular connection should get the message before terminating because of EOF on its stdin.

---

#### Solution

If you don't want connections to terminate because of EOF on the stdin of `socat`, tell the tool not to read from this address. From `man 1 socat`:

> `-u` Uses unidirectional mode. The first address is only used for reading, and the second address is only used for writing […].
>
> `-U` Uses unidirectional mode in reverse direction. The first address is only used for writing, and the second address is only used for reading.

In your case `-` (meaning `STDIO`) is the second address, so you need `-u`:

```
nohup socat -u -x -d -d -d tcp-l:8080,bind=0.0.0.0,fork,reuseaddr - 2>stderr.log >stdout.log &
```